# Syntax error in IPython 2.2.0

Tags: ipython

I'm running IPython 2.2.0 in Anaconda on Windows 8, and I'm running into an error with a code that is supposed to find the value of a stock option.

Here's my code:

```
SO = 100.
K = 105.
T = 1.0
r = 0.05
sigma = 0.2
from numpy import *
I = 100000
z = random.standard_normal(I)
ST = SO * exp((r - 0.5 * sigma ** 2) * T + sigma * sqrt(T) * z)
hT = maximum(ST - K, 0)
CO = exp(-r * T) * sum(hT) / I
print "Value of the European Call Option %5.3f" % CO
```

When I run the print command on the last line, it's telling me that it's invalid syntax and has an arrow beneath the second quotation mark (next to the %5.3f".  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the print function. You are using Python version that allows `print()` as a function....seems to suggest that iPython 2.2.0 is probably using Python 3.x version underneath (just my guess, but can be wrong).

Try the following instead:

```
print("Value of the European Call Option %5.3f" % CO)
```

This should work...

Comment: It worked!  The book I'm using didn't have the parentheses, and I realize that's required for Python 3.  I think I tried to add the parentheses earlier and put them in wrong, like: print ("Value of the European Call Option %5.3f") % CO

Comment: @Brandon         please ignore the semicolon.....I work with 3 languages C++,Java,Python....and always end up finishing my statements with a semicolon...just a slave of habit...It's not a standard Python practice to use semicolon (but doesn't kill if you if you've done so..). Edited the answer now...:)